How to add rounded borders that cling to a Text in SwiftUI
I want to create something like this:

The background/highlight effect is a rounded rectangle with .regularMaterial and .stroke(.black).
I have tried using AttributedString and setting the .backgroundColor but this doesn't allow me to use materials, nor can I round the edges.
I tried calculating this "precise" / "clingy" border using information about the font, but Text sometimes automatically hyphenates long words unpredictably and thus my calculations get messed up. I have simply disabled hyphenation for now but I'm wondering if someone has figured out a way to do this.
I thought of rendering each line separately but then again Text doesn't tell me where in the text the line breaks will be, so I didn't try this method.

One way to approach this is to use a Canvas to show the text:

a Canvas receives a GraphicsContext, which can be used to measure the width of some text
the source string can be broken up into words and then re-assembled line by line, adding as many words to a line that will fit
as each line is processed, a rounded rectangle can be added to a background path using .union
once all lines have been processed, the background path can be filled and stroked, then the text can be shown over this filled shape.

It's a bit clumsy, especially in the way the text is broken up and then re-assembled, but it gets close to the result you were after. However, the one thing I couldn't get to work was the Material background. If you try to use GraphicsContext.fill to fill a path using a Material style, it just fills with black (like redacted text). I created a new post to try to find a solution to this. In the meantime, the version below uses a semi-transparent background instead:
struct ContentView: View {
    private typealias Strings = [String]
    let horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 6
    let verticalPadding: CGFloat = 2
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 2
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 6

    let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    private func wordsForOneLine(allWords: Strings, startingAt: Int, ctx: GraphicsContext, size: CGSize) -> Strings {
        var result = Strings()

        // Measure the size of the text using a larger rectangle,
        // so as to avoid word wrap
        let largeSize = CGSize(width: size.width + 1000, height: size.height + 1000)
        let nWordsTotal = allWords.count
        var nWordsInLine = 0
        while startingAt + nWordsInLine < nWordsTotal {
            var tmpResult = result
            tmpResult.append(allWords[startingAt + nWordsInLine])
            let text = Text(tmpResult.joined(separator: " "))
            let resolvedText = ctx.resolve(text)
            let lineWidth = resolvedText.measure(in: largeSize).width
            if lineWidth <= size.width {
                result = tmpResult
            } else {
                break
            }
            nWordsInLine += 1
        }
        return result
    }

    private func textLines(fullText: String, ctx: GraphicsContext, size: CGSize) -> Strings {
        var result = Strings()
        let allWords = fullText.components(separatedBy: " ")
        let nWordsTotal = allWords.count
        var startingAt = 0
        while startingAt < nWordsTotal {
            let words = wordsForOneLine(allWords: allWords, startingAt: startingAt, ctx: ctx, size: size)
            if !words.isEmpty {
                result.append(words.joined(separator: " "))
                startingAt += words.count
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    private func processLines(
        lines: Strings,
        ctx: GraphicsContext,
        size: CGSize,
        action: (String, CGSize, CGFloat) -> Void
    ) {
        var y = CGFloat.zero
        for line in lines {
            let text = Text(line)
            let resolvedText = ctx.resolve(text)
            let textSize = resolvedText.measure(in: size)
            if y == 0 {
                let fullHeight = CGFloat(lines.count) * textSize.height
                y = (size.height - fullHeight) / 2
            }
            action(line, textSize, y)
            y += textSize.height
        }
    }

    private func renderText(text: String) -> some View {
        Canvas { ctx, size in
            var backgroundPath = Path()
            let reducedSize = CGSize(
                width: size.width - (2 * horizontalPadding) - lineWidth,
                height: size.height - (2 * verticalPadding) - lineWidth
            )
            let lines = textLines(fullText: text, ctx: ctx, size: reducedSize)
            processLines(lines: lines, ctx: ctx, size: reducedSize) { line, size, y in
                let paddedRect = CGRect(
                    x: lineWidth / 2,
                    y: y - verticalPadding + (lineWidth / 2),
                    width: size.width + (2 * horizontalPadding),
                    height: size.height + (2 * verticalPadding)
                )
                backgroundPath = backgroundPath.union(
                    Path(roundedRect: paddedRect, cornerSize: .init(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
                )
            }
            ctx.fill(
                backgroundPath,
                with: .palette([.color(white: 1, opacity: 0.8), .style(.regularMaterial)])
            )
            if lineWidth > 0 {
                ctx.stroke(backgroundPath, with: .color(.black), lineWidth: lineWidth)
            }
            processLines(lines: lines, ctx: ctx, size: reducedSize) { line, size, y in
                let rect = CGRect(origin: .init(x: horizontalPadding, y: y), size: size)
                ctx.draw(Text(line), in: rect)
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        renderText(text: loremIpsum)
            .font(.title2)
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color(red: 0.871, green: 0.863, blue: 0.855))
    }
}


A Canvas is greedy and consumes all the space available. If you want to restrict the height of the rendered text to the minimum necessary then you could use the technique of a hidden footprint, with the Canvas shown in an overlay:
Text(loremIpsum)
    .padding(.horizontal, horizontalPadding + (lineWidth / 2))
    .padding(.vertical, verticalPadding + (lineWidth / 2))
    .hidden()
    .overlay { renderText(text: loremIpsum) }
    .font(.title2)
    .padding()
    // .background(.yellow)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color(red: 0.871, green: 0.863, blue: 0.855))

It turns out that the hidden version reserves a little more height than necessary, because Text adds a little spacing between the wrapped lines. The function renderText does not include any spacing between lines, but you could add it if you wanted to. See also How to get the default LineSpacing of a font in SwiftUI? (which I've now noticed was your question!).

A sample of code that uses these concepts is shown here:
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
      Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,")
          .font(.title)
          .padding() // Add padding around the text
          .background(Material.regular, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)) // Apply rounded material background
          .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)) // Ensure the clipping matches the rounded corners
          .padding() // Additional outer padding for aesthetics
    }
}



Hi, the rectangle doesn't cling to the text. I've updated the photo to better show the effect I'm trying to achieve
